How to share a complex object instance to multiple processes in python
how can I share the instance of a class between multiple processes?
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 50  # Initial speed

    def update_speed(self, new_speed):
        self.speed = new_speed  # Method to update speed

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed  # Method to get current speed
car = Car()

How do I access this car instance between multiple processes implemented by the concurrency library in Python?
I tried doing some shenanigans, with help from the internet; but they didn't quite work out. Here is the attempt:
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import time

class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 50  # Initial speed

    def update_speed(self, new_speed):
        self.speed = new_speed  # Method to update speed

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed  # Method to get current speed

def run(shared_car):
    while True:
        print("Worker checking database...")
        shared_car.update_speed(200)  # Worker updates speed
        print(f"Worker updated speed to: {shared_car.get_speed()}")
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        # Create a proxy object for Car
        CarProxy = manager.Namespace()
        CarProxy.car = Car()

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            # Submit the worker task
            executor.submit(run, CarProxy.car)

            try:
                # Main process monitoring and modifying shared object
                while True:
                    print(f"Main process reads speed: {CarProxy.car.get_speed()}")
                    if CarProxy.car.get_speed() == 200:
                        print("Main process resetting speed to 100.")
                        CarProxy.car.update_speed(100)  # Main modifies the object
                        print(f"Main process reads speed: {CarProxy.car.get_speed()}")
                    time.sleep(2)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Terminating...")

The How: When I tried to modify the instance from the main script it didn't update the attributes in the processes. I am still very new to multiprocessing shenanigans might have messed up.

I wanted to know how to share nested ones to be specific
